# How to make shortcut key for Wrap with Abbreviation in SublineText?

Tags: css, emmet

It seems there is no default shortcut for "**Wrap with Abbreviation**" **Emmet** in Windows.
How to create this shortcut key for **SublineText**?

Comment: https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin#all-my-keyboard-shortcuts-gonenothing-works

Comment: @sergey-chikuyonok I get this error when I wanted to save: https://i.ibb.co/Xybx1nZ/st-error.png